# Enzyme find node created with createContainer (React.PureComponent)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, chai, enzyme

I have a wrapper component similar to the following:

```js
/* Some imports here */

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  renderChildren() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return children.map(child =>
      <Child key={child._id} />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderChildren()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Wrapper.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.array,
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  let children = [];
  const subscriptions = [
     Meteor.subscribe('Collection.all'),
     /* ... */
  ];
  if (subscriptions.every(sub => sub.ready()) {
     /* Some irrelevant code here */
     children = Collection.find({}).fetch();
  }
  return { children };
}, Wrapper);
```

And the Child component is similar to:

```js
/* Some imports here */

class Child extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
   /* Some irrelevant code here that has to stay in createContainer (and not constructor)*/
}, Child);
```

I am attempting to write a test that, whenever a Document is inserted to the Collection, I compare if the length (amount) of Child components in Wrapper is incremented correctly. Before, when I did not need to use createContainer in my child element, the following:

```js
it('should render with some children and reactively update with them', () => {
  let children = [];
  _.times(4, () => children.push(Factory.create('doc'));
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Wrapper />
  );
  chai.assert.notEqual(wrapper.find('Child').length, children.length);
  wrapper.setProps({ children });
  chai.assert.equal(wrapper.find('Child').length, children.length);
}
```

Did work as intended but as I added `createContainer` for the child element also the previously worked test(s) started to fail. It appears that enzyme's `find('Child')` function does not return any of these nodes anymore. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is this `item` you are referring to in the test? Shouldn't it be `wrapper`?

Comment: Typo in question, fixed.

Comment: What was the code _before_ you've added `createContainer`? It's really confusing.

Comment: And another question about `children = Collection.find({});`: shouldn't it be `children = Collection.find({}).fetch();`? React would accept `Array` only, not `Cursor`.

Comment: createContainer is basicly a wrapper around the React component, returning a React.PureComponent. It may be used to manipulate the component's properties (such as props) and to make database calls before the initial rendering happens. In the example code above I have not included any of this as it is irrelevant to the question. The problem I am facing is purely an enzyme problem as it does not find any of these components that are wrapped inside (by) createContainer.